# Nginx redirect selected URL from http to https

Tags: nginx, redirect

I have the Nginx config as follows. I have both HTTP and HTTPS servers setup. Now, I want to redirect all the HTTP under domain.com/admin to HTTPS. How should I do do it?

URL that I want to redirect to HTTPS.

domain.com/admin

domain.com/admin/mypage/

domain.com/admin/mypage/?id=1

domain.com/admin/mypage/sub?id=1

...

```
upstream web {  
  ip_hash;
  server web:8000;
}

# portal
server {  
    listen 8000 default_server;
    
    location / {
        return 301 https://localhost$request_uri;
    }

    server_name localhost;
}

# portal (https)                                                                                                   
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name localhost;
   
    ssl    on;
    ssl_certificate    /etc/nginx/conf.d/mynginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key    /etc/nginx/conf.d/mynginx.key;

    location /media  {
        alias  /media;  # your Django project  media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        alias  /static; # your Django project  static files - amend as required
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web/;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that you already have an unconditional redirect for any URI from HTTP on port 8000 to HTTPS on port 443. You want to change it the way that redirect would only happens for `/admin/...` URIs?

Comment: The `return` statement should use the domain name of your server, not `localhost`.